# CKEditor publisher toolbar missing from WYGWAM on ExpressionEngine 1.7

Tags: wygwam, ckeditor

First...all of this is going to sound very novice...because it is.
We had an issue at the server level and the WYGWAM broke. It's been restored by the Publisher(ish) toolbar is missing.
I seriously need some help with this.  I cannot find the location of the redirect and our Developer is no longer with us.

From our host:
the page layout does appear to be missing the small bar of icons below "Main Content".  The Inspect Element tool also shows a mixed content error that endlessly generates; this can be explained by the looping requests to http://www.specialmade.com/files_includes/css/wygwam.css that are visible in the network tab.  The issue is that the wygwam.css is being loaded insecurely, and thus failing.  When you visit this via https, it works:

https://www.specialmade.com/files_includes/css/wygwam.css

This shows there's no redirect, but that the edit page is calling this URL with the wrong security(http versus https).  I understand this issue became apparent after we restored your files and database;

Comment: Have you gone to `Admin` -> `Weblog Administration` -> `System Preferences` -> `General Configuration` and verified that the URLs begin with "https://"?